# Aligning card-body of accordion to top right from the card header

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

A normal accordion works by expanding downwards. I would like my Boostrap Vue accordion(https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/collapse/#accordion-support), on expansion, to align the `card-body` to the top right from the `card-headers`.

A normal accordion:

[image: Normal Accordion]

**I want**: The expanded header(`card-body`) is aligned to the top right. I would like all the expansions to be aligned to the top right. Like below:

[image: Accordion Wanted]

I have managed to align the `card-header` to the left and `card-body` to the right, like this:

[image: current]

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1150px;
  }

  header.card-header {
    float: left !important;
    width: 25% !important;
  }

  .card-body {
    width: 70%;
    float: right !important;
  }
```

I don't know how I could align the `card-body` to the top. Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: You want card-body 2 to be aligned where card-header 1 is? 
you got a jsfilddle with your code and html?

Comment: Have you made the card-body's position absolute? If you do that it might give you the desired effect.

Comment: @EdenWebStudio yes, that's correct. So any card-header's expansion would be aligned where card-header 1 is.

Comment: @Muderino I just did and now the card-body overlaps with my card-headers.

Comment: You've to set the left-property to always be wider than your headers.

Comment: @Muderino hey could you elaborate on that, please? you mean the left: x of my card-body should be greater than the width of the card-header?

Comment: @AlyssaAlex set     position: absolute; left: calc(20% + 10px); The left property can become whatever you want. And yes, the x should be greated than the width of your card-header

Comment: @Muderino thanks for your answer, I did what you mentioned and yes they are more to the right like how I wanted it but, but on the expansion of the card-header(card-body) down the list are still near their respective card-header and not near card-header1. Any idea?

Comment: did you set the top property? e.g top: 10px